# Search videos on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-videos

How can I search videos on Facebook like we search on YouTube?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look via URL at `https://www.facebook.com/search/videos/?q=fish`
which will give you videos on Facebook about fish.

Alternately, just do a search and choose video from the tabs.

[image]